# Are there choices to make along the campaign?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Wings of Liberty, there were two missions [where you could choose who to side with](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4837/14) and there were differences in the story according to what you did.

Are there such missions in Heart of the Swarm? If so, what are the differences between choosing one or the other option (as regards to the story and rewards if any)?

Comment: Answers for this question should be spoilered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From what I played of the campaign, there doesn't seem to be decisions about the plot.
>
> Most of the decisions are about which strain you have to chose from since these choices are irreversible.
>
> The rest of the decisions can be changed between missions.